# Ionic 2 File Storage

Tags: file, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently trying to write a PDF that was created using PDFMake to file, and then take that file and attach it to an email. I have spent 6 hours trying to do this and I keep getting errors.

Below is my code for exporting the PDF. I tested the PDF in serve using createPDF.open() and it worked. I have also printed the Base64 data in the console.

```
exportPDF() {
    console.log("ExportPDF()")
    this.pdf = pdfMake;
    // For use in browser(web)
    //this.pdf.createPdf(getDocDefinition(this.issues, this.project, this.report)).open();
    let data : string;
    let newPDF;


    this.pdf.createPdf(getDocDefinition(this.issues, this.project, this.report)).getBase64((buffer) => {
      data = buffer;
      console.log("newPDF: " + data)
    });

    // this.pdf.createPdf(getDocDefinition(this.issues, this.project, this.report)).getBuffer((buffer) => {
    //   data = buffer.toArrayBuffer();
    //   console.log("newPDF: " + data)
    // });


    // Platforms
    if (this.plat.is('ios')) {
      console.log("Platform: ios")

      let file = "testFingering.pdf"

      console.log(cordova.file.cacheDirectory);

      File.removeFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, file);
      File.writeFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, file, data).then(() => {
        // Success!
        console.log("writeFile: success!")

        SocialSharing.share("tits", "tits", cordova.file.cacheDirectory + file).then(() => {
          // Success!
          console.log("shareViaEmail: success!")
        }).catch((err) => {
          // Error!
          console.log("shareViaEmail: fail!  " + err)
        });

      }).catch((err) => {
        // Error!
        console.log("writeFile: fail!  " + JSON.stringify(err));
      });

    } else if (this.plat.is('android')) {
      console.log("Platform: android")

    } else if (this.plat.is('windows')) {
      console.log("Platform: windows")

    } else {
      console.log("Platform: web")

    }

  }
```

Here are the errors I am receiving:

```
2017-01-31 20:40:12.997343 CMTA[1725:417453] writeFile: fail!  {"code":12,"message":"PATH_EXISTS_ERR"}
2017-01-31 20:40:13.013456 CMTA[1725:417453] writeFile: fail!  {"code":"Invalid parameter type"}
```

I am only executing this code once, so 1) I am not sure why it is logging two errors.

2) I know "PATH_EXISTS_ERR" means the path already exists, but if you look in the code, I am deleting the file and recreating it every time.

3) What parameter should I be inputing? It says it will accept "text", should I be using something else? I tried toBufferArray() before because that's what I did in my Ionic 1 version of this app, but that isn't working anymore.

I would greatly appreciate any help as this is frustrating me to no end.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up getting everything. I had to do two steps though.

1) I had to move the File.writeFile() into the response from my createPDF() call.

2) I had to getBuffer() instead of getBase64() and then found a function on the internet for toBufferArray().

Here is the final code:

```
exportPDF() {
    console.log("ExportPDF()")
    this.pdf = pdfMake;
    // For use in browser(web)
    //this.pdf.createPdf(getDocDefinition(this.issues, this.project, this.report)).open();
    let data;
    let file = "test11.pdf";
    let newPDF;


    this.pdf.createPdf(getDocDefinition(this.issues, this.project, this.report)).getBuffer((buffer) => {
      data = this.toArrayBuffer(buffer);
      console.log("newPDF: " + data);
      console.log(cordova.file.cacheDirectory + file);
      File.removeFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, file);
      File.writeFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, file, data, true).then(() => {
        // Success!
        console.log("writeFile: success!");

        SocialSharing.share("tits", "tits", cordova.file.cacheDirectory + file).then(() => {
          // Success!
          console.log("shareViaEmail: success!")
        }).catch((err) => {
          // Error!
          console.log("shareViaEmail: fail!  " + err)
        });

      }).catch((err) => {
        // Error!
        console.log("writeFile: fail!  " + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
    });

    // this.pdf.createPdf(getDocDefinition(this.issues, this.project, this.report)).getBuffer((buffer) => {
    //   data = buffer.toArrayBuffer();
    //   console.log("newPDF: " + data)
    // });

  }

  toArrayBuffer(buf) {
    let ab = new ArrayBuffer(buf.length);
    let view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
      view[i] = buf[i];
    }
    return ab;
  }
```